# xpath support in android 2.0.1

Tags: android

android is supporting `javax.xml.xpath.XPath` in api level 8 ie 2.2
But i am writing some application for 2.0.1  in that there is a need for 
XPath parser. 
I downloaded jar file from aml-apis.jar
But when i added the jar file to my application i got the following build 
error

```
trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class": 
[2010-12-21 15:49:59 - Client] 

Attempt to include a core class (java.* or javax.*) in something other 
than a core library. It is likely that you have attempted to include 
in an application the core library (or a part thereof) from a desktop 
virtual machine. This will most assuredly not work. At a minimum, it 
jeopardizes the compatibility of your app with future versions of the 
platform. It is also often of questionable legality.   


If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only 
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine distribution, 
as opposed to compiling an application -- then use the 
"--core-library" option to suppress this error message.   


If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact building an 
application, then be forewarned that your application will still fail 
to build or run, at some point. Please be prepared for angry customers 
who find, for example, that your application ceases to function once 
they upgrade their operating system. You will be to blame for this 
problem. 


If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a core 
package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to repackage 
that code. That is, move the classes in question into your own package 
namespace. This means that they will never be in conflict with core 
system classes. If you find that you cannot do this, then that is an 
indication that the path you are on will ultimately lead to pain, 
suffering, grief, and lamentation. 


    [2010-12-21 15:49:59 - Client] 1 error; aborting 
    [2010-12-21 15:49:59 - Client] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 
    1
```

Please help me!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is for you:

The Force Unleashed: XML+XPath On Android Using Dom4j And Jaxen

http://kcy.me/1fr8

Comment: Yes it worked.  But now I get 
trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class": this error